# Airflow dag changes are not reflecting

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have airflow configured to run on local executor. When the dag count is less than 150 approx, everything will work.. current the dag count is around 350 and the changes made in dag code and import errors are not updating.

Can anyone please help?

I tried changing parallelism and max_dag parameters, still not working

Comment: Try to add more information like  below.
share config values for parallelism and max_dag.
run airflow dags test <dag-id> from terminal and share the logs